# Apostrophe Usage Around Words?

Tags: punctuation, apostrophe, quotations, quotation-marks

> "The Canadian smiled at his opponent as they went to their corners. It was not a smile that said, ‘I got this now.’"

In *‘I got this now.’*, what seems a grammatical reason for this (apostrophes)? Why, and when, may you use these, if you can, in other writing?

Comment: They are single quotation marks, marking a quotation inside another quotation marked with double quotes. This is the common US use of single and double quotes; most British publishers reverse the two, putting single quotes around the primary quotation and reserving double quotes for an embedded quotation.

Comment: Oh, no, no. I quoted this. In writing I got it from, it did not contain quotes. It went *The Canadian smiled at his opponent as they went to their corners. It was not a smile that said, ‘I got this now.’*

Comment: Ah ... looking at the source it appears that this writer employs single quotes to mark this as not-a-real-quotation but something imagined.

Comment: Yes. Yes. That. So may that seem like a grammatically proper use for that punctuation mark? May you use it like that?

Comment: Oh, dear. You may do almost anything you like with punctuation, and the frank truth is that nobody except publishers and people who mark student essays cares much. If you're still a student, do what your teacher tells you; if you're getting paid for your work, do what your paymaster tells you; and in other situations use whatever conventions make sense to you.

Answer (score 1):

Those are not apostrophes; they are quotation marks, which are used to indicate when someone is speaking, or that you are quoting from another source. When using quotation marks, alternate between double quotes and single quotes, starting with double quotes.

The sentence in your example goes two levels deep, but you can go more, though it may get confusing.

> John said, "Jane told me, 'John, I like the movie that starts with, "A
>   long time ago in a galaxy far, far away...". Do you remember that one?'".